# How to disable dropdown input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, disabled-input

I'm trying to disable input and choice from an existing dropdown menu field. I want to make it load already chosen selections from the menu without giving the user the opportunity to change them in any way. That's the code I have:

HTML:

```
<select data-chosen-width="100%" multiple="multiple" data-chosen-disable-search="" data-placeholder="Choose categories" name="project_category" id="project_category" class="chosen multi-tax-item tax-item required cat_profile" style="display: none;">
    <option class=" administrativno cat-115 level-0" value="115">Административно право</option>
    <option class=" veshtno cat-120 level-0" value="120">Вещно право</option>
    <option class=" danachno cat-127 level-0" value="127" selected="selected">Данъчно право</option>
    <option class=" mpp cat-125 level-0" value="125">Международно публично право</option>
    <option class=" mchp cat-126 level-0" value="126">Международно частно право</option>
    <option class=" nakazatelno cat-117 level-0" value="117">Наказателно право</option>
    <option class=" obligatsionno cat-121 level-0" value="121" selected="selected">Облигационно право</option>
    <option class=" osiguritelno cat-124 level-0" value="124" selected="selected">Осигурително право</option>
    <option class=" pravo-na-es cat-128 level-0" value="128">Право на Европейския съюз</option>
    <option class=" pris cat-123 level-0" value="123">Право на интелектуалната собственост</option>
    <option class=" semeino-nasledstveno cat-119 level-0" value="119">Семейно и наследствено право</option>
    <option class=" trudovo cat-116 level-0" value="116">Трудово право</option>
    <option class=" targovsko cat-122 level-0" value="122">Търговско право</option>
    <option class=" finansovo cat-118 level-0" value="118">Финансово право</option>
</select>

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 350px;" title="" id="project_category_chosen">
  <ul class="chosen-choices">
    <li class="search-choice">
      <span>Данъчно право</span>
      <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="2"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="search-choice">
      <span>Облигационно право</span>
      <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="6"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="search-choice">
      <span>Осигурително право</span>
      <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="7"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="search-field">
      <input value="Choose categories" class="valid" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;" type="text">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
$cate_arr = array();

if(!empty($profile->tax_input['project_category'])){
    foreach ($profile->tax_input['project_category'] as $key => $value) {
        $cate_arr[] = $value->term_id;
    };
}

ae_tax_dropdown(
    'project_category',
    array(
        'attr'            => 'data-chosen-width="100%" multiple="multiple" data-chosen-disable-search="" data-placeholder="'.__("Choose categories", ET_DOMAIN).'"',
        'class'           => 'chosen multi-tax-item tax-item required cat_profile',
        'hide_empty'      => false,
        'hierarchical'    => true ,
        'id'              => 'project_category' ,
        'selected'        => $cate_arr,
        'show_option_all' => false
    )
);
```

I've tried adding some code samples I found on the web, but nothing has actually worked so far. Will be glad if you come up with some ideas or solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by adding disabled="true" to the 'attr' of ae_tax_dropdown', so it now looks like this:

```
'attr'            => 'data-chosen-width="100%" multiple="multiple" data-chosen-disable-search="" data-placeholder="'.__("Choose categories", ET_DOMAIN).'" disabled="true"'
```

Answer (score 0):

try add attribute disabled="disabled" to select. 
e.g

```
<select disabled="disabled"></select>
```

if you are using PHP to write. please try output these code to page:

```
<script>
    $('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried adding this after ?> in the same div as the PHP code above, but it didn't make a difference. I also tried adding it to the functions.php (it's a Wordpress theme and website), but it didn't work there either :/

Comment: try this code: <script> setTimeout(function() { $('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled') }, 500)  </script> , replace above of it.

Comment: Tried that one as well, but it didn't work either. The thing is that the <script<>/script> code actually gets loaded in the HTML, but stays there as it doesn't refer to anything, although it is actually located in the div for the section. I'm adding it after the ?> PHP mark, which is located exactly after the end of the code snippet I've posted above. Should I somehow enter it inside the PHP code, so that it would get related to the section and start working? Thanks!